# Texmaker error reports on wrong line

Tags: texmaker, debugging

I find that texmaker reports undefined control sequence on a line or two past where the error is. How to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think this has a fix since it is dependent on a specific compiler. Note that Texmaker cannot precisely determine the error rather the packages highlight where they cannot continue since their syntax is broken. Most packages give generic error messages.

Comment: I think your only option is to report this to the maintainer of Texmaker, I don't think we can do anything about how it parses the log file.